# Need help creating a program that finds lightest and heaviest dog

Tags: java, arraylist, accessor, modifier

I  am have a huge amount of trouble with this Java project. I have to Write a class that Keeps         Track of the name, breed, date, and weight of the dog I must input a file containing one line per dog. I need an accessor,modifier, Arraylist and a toString Method. The main program then needs to determine the lightest dog and heaviest dog.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Kennel
{

 public static void main(String args[]) 
 {

  String line = ""; // string var to hold entire line

  if (args.length < 1)
   {
    System.out.println("\n   You forgot to put a file name on the command line.");
    System.exit(1);
   };


   String inFile = args[0];  // file name off command line
   Scanner sc = null;
    try
   {
   sc = new Scanner(new File(inFile));
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
    System.out.println("File not found");
    System.exit(1);
     }

     // print a message explaining the purpose of the program.
    System.out.println("\nThis program inputs file ");
    System.out.println(args[0]);
    System.out.println("and outputs information about all the dogs in the registry.");
    System.out.println("\nWritten by Phil Trout.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Property           "+"Name                   "+"Value         ");
    System.out.println();
    // Loop

   //double heaviest = 0.0;
   //double lightest = 1000.0;  

     while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {

    // read a line from the input file via sc into line
    line = sc.nextLine();

    }

    {
    //got from  email infromation   


    StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(line);
    String name = stk.nextToken();
    String breed = stk.nextToken();
    int month = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
    int day = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
    int year = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
    double weight = Double.parseDouble(stk.nextToken());



    Dog list = new Dog(name, breed, month, day, year, weight);

    ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
    dogs.add(list);

    double firstweight = dogs.get(0).getWeight();

    System.out.println(firstweight);         


    for (int i = 0; i< dogs.size(); i++)
   {
   double newweight = dogs.get(i).getWeight();       
   }








 public class Dog
 {
  private String dogName;
  private String dogBreed;
  private int dogMonth;
  private int dogDay;
  private int dogYear;
  private double dogWeight;

public Dog(String name, String breed, int month, int day, int year, double weight)
{
  dogName = name;
  dogBreed = breed;
  dogMonth = month;
  dogDay = day;
  dogYear = year;
  dogWeight = weight;
 } 
  public String getName()
{
 return dogName;
 }

public String getBreed()
{
return dogBreed;
}
public String toString()
{
return String.format("%d/%d/%d", dogMonth, dogDay, dogYear);





}
public double getWeight()
{
return dogWeight;
}
```

Comment: Solve this problem one by one. What is going on right now? Can you even get it to run? What results are you getting? You need to be able to understand your own code for us to help you

Comment: Take a look at Math.min and Math.max

Comment: Right now the program is only printing the last wight of the file . If i replacedogs.get(1).getWeight(); with dogs.get(0).getWeight(); I get an  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException error.

Comment: Take a look at the anser here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550817/java-finding-printing-min-max-with-array. You can solve your problem on a similar way.

Comment: > Right now the program is only printing the last wight of the file
Think about what this could mean, off the top of my head, I can only think of four scenarios: 
1. You are manually printing off only the last weight 
2. You only add one weight, the last one 
3. You keep readding the same weight 
4. All weights are the same. 
Narrow down which one is possible, and you have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things that you did  right btu you placed in the wrong place.
a) extracting the values from the line, b) creating the dog instance, c) adding the dog to the list,  it all should happen inside the loop. Otherwise you will only get the last value in the file.

```
   ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>(); 

 while(sc.hasNextLine())
{

// read a line from the input file via sc into line
  line = sc.nextLine();
  StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(line);
  String name = stk.nextToken();
  String breed = stk.nextToken();
  int month = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
  int day = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
  int year = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
  double weight = Double.parseDouble(stk.nextToken());

  Dog list = new Dog(name, breed, month, day, year, weight);

  dogs.add(list);

}
```

**Update**

```
 int lightestIndex = 0;
 int heaviestIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i< dogs.size(); i++)
{
   if(dogs.get(i).getWeight() <= dogs.get(lightestIndex).getWeight()){
      lightestIndex = i;
   } 

   if(dogs.get(i).getWeight() >= dogs.get(heaviestIndex).getWeight()){
      heaviestIndex = i;
   }        
}


 System.out.println("The Lightest dog is " + dogs.get(lightestIndex).toString());
 System.out.println("The Heaviest dog is " + dogs.get(heaviestIndex).toString());
```

Comment: Or you can show me what you have tried for the second part of the question and then I will include the rest of the answer

Comment: for (int i = 0; i< dogs.size(); i++)
   {
   double newweight =         dogs.get(i).getWeight();    
   }
    //double nextweight = dogs.get(i).getWeight();
  }
  
   /*if (firstweight > nextweight)
   {
   nextweight = firstweight ;  
   }
    System.out.println(firstweight);*/
   
  }

Comment: I can see what you tried to do. I think this would be more like it.

double lightWeight = dogs.get(0).getWeight(); 
double heavyWeight = dogs.get(0).getWeight();

for (int i = 0; i< dogs.size(); i++) { 
double newweight = dogs.get(i).getWeight(); 
if (lightWeight > newweight) {
 lightWeight = newweight ;  
}
if (heavyWeight < newweight) {
 heavyWeight = newweight ;  
}
}

Comment: Can you help me with the toString part in the Dog class . I need the day, month, year and weight in it.

Comment: Then you just need to include it in the toString() method. You can check out string formatting here. https://www.udemy.com/blog/java-format-string/